# SelectedIndex not inserting correct value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, combobox

I have a method to insert user information into the SQL Server database. I have my combobox populate on pageload event. The user selects the input they want and hit update if they are updating a old record or insert if creating a new record. When they do so my database is not storing the right value if they select 4 it stores 3. Here is my insert method and populate method.

Insert method: I have to join the `StockID` because it is a primary key.

```
using (dbConn2 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["tville"].ToString()))
{
   SqlCommand addNewFormat = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO PackLabelFormat ( PackFormatID, Description, PrintWeight, PrintPlantCode, PrintPrice, StockID) VALUES (@PackFormatID, @Description, @PrintWeight, @PrintPlantCode, @PrintPrice, (SELECT @StockID from LabelStockReference LSR WHERE LSR.StockID = @StockID))", dbConn2);

   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackFormatID", Convert.ToInt32(IDselect));
   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", rTxtBoxDescription.Text);
   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrintPrice", rChkBoxPrintPrice.Checked);
   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrintWeight", rChkBoxWeight.Checked);
   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrintPlantCode", rChkBoxPlantCode.Checked);
   addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockID", Convert.ToInt32(cmboBoxStock.SelectedIndex));

   dbConn2.Open();
   addNewFormat.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Populate method:

```
if (labelList != null)
{
   foreach (LabelData l in labelList)
   {
       cmboBoxStock.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", l.PackFormatID, l.Description));
   }
}
```

If there is anything else I'm leaving out just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code which may involve **SelectedIndex** here? Also please tag the UI technology you use.

Comment: @KingKing addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockID", Convert.ToInt32(cmboBoxStock.SelectedIndex)); It's right above dbconn2.open();

Comment: You **cannot** mix the `INSERT .. VALUES(..)` method with a `SELECT` inside its `VALUES()` collection. Either you use `VALUES()` and provide **literal values and SQL Server variables` only, or then you have to use the `INSERT ... SELECT ....` method to select from that table (and possibly provide other values as literals)

Comment: @marc_s So you saying either do all the values that way or have static values? I didn't full follow your post. I had found on another stack post where they used what I implemented.

Comment: @marc_s if you could elaborate with some code for reference that would really help me learn.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: see my response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for your INSERT statement:

**(1)** you can use `INSERT ... VALUES ....` and in this case, you must supply as many values as you have columns to insert data into, and you have to supply **literal values** or SQL Server variables only - you **cannot** use a `SELECT` to provide a value:

```
 DECLARE @ASqlServerVariable VARCHAR(100)
 SET @ASqlServerVariable = 'any possible value that's legal for this datatype'

 INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) 
 VALUES (42, 'Some fixed value', @ASqlServerVariable, 'Another literal value')
```

What you *could* do is use a `SELECT` to store the value you're interested in into a SQL Server variable:

```
DECLARe @StockID INT

SELECT @StockID = ID 
FROM dbo.LabelStockReference LSR 
WHERE LSR.StockID = 4711
```

**(2)** if you can't provide all literal values or variables, then you must use the `INSERT .... SELECT ...` option, which requires you to provide as many columns in your `SELECT` as the `INSERT` expects to insert a row into the target table:

```
 DECLARE @ASqlServerVariable VARCHAR(100)
 SET @ASqlServerVariable = 'any possible value that's legal for this datatype'

 INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ID, Col1, Col2, Col3) 
    SELECT 
        42, 'Some fixed value', @ASqlServerVariable, aTableColumn
    FROM
        dbo.SomeOtherTable
```

See the [official TechNet documentation for `INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for all the details and exact syntax of all possible options etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first SelectedIndex is 0, and your first ID is 1 ,so just make this change:

```
addNewFormat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockID", Convert.ToInt32(cmboBoxStock.SelectedIndex)+1);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you, but it is set default at 0 why wouldn't read the first value as being in the 0 spot?

Comment: If you want the value, use SelectedValue property. But if you want the selected index, use the SelectedIndex property and remember that the first index is 0.

Comment: So my combobox that has the values looks at the top record as 0 to 7 in my case so when I was selecting label 2 my index was returning 1. That's why the value needs to be increased by one.